# Python Discord Bot - Youtube-dl not searching using full search query

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

I don't really know how to explain this so sorry if the title is awful. Basically, I have youtube-dl set up on my bot and it works perfectly with a URL but say if I put >play cute cat, it will only search for 'cute' instead of the full thing. How do I sort this?

Here is the code;

````
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):

await client.say('```Playing```')

server = ctx.message.server
voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url, ytdl_options={'default_search': 'auto'})
players[server.id] = player
player.start()
````